# Regex not validating consistently

Tags: php, regex

I'm experiencing an usual problem and I can't seem to nail down the cause. I'm working on `server side validation` for a number of fields on a signup form on a site. This is the block of `PHP`:

```
if ('phone-name' == $tag->name) {
        $value = $_POST[$tag->name];
        if (!preg_match('/\+([0-9])([ .-]*\d){7,12}/', $value)) {
            $result->invalidate($tag, "You must enter a valid number: $value is not valid");
        }
    }
```

The `regex` I am using should only allow the user to input:

- the "+" sign
- spaces, dots and hyphens
- and any number from 0 to 9

However when I run the following tests I get these results:

TEST 1: INVALID INPUT

```
+3588<script>alert(1)</script>
```

TEST 2: VALID INPUT

`+35388888888<script>alert(1)</script>`

Is there something I am missing here? How come the regex works for TEST 2 and not for TEST 1? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why would that get downvoted? perfectly valid question

Comment: to match, number with range `0-9` needs to be repeated `{7,12}` min `7` to max `12` times. Now, `3588` is four, so doesn't match, `35388888888` is `11` so it matches

Comment: What is `<script>alert(1)</script>`?

Comment: Ok so TEST 2 is passing because I have 11 digits, TEST 1 is failing because I only have 4?

Comment: I'm doing testing, I want to ensure that no one can input script tags, currently they can

Comment: @Javacadabra yes, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/iJ8uL8/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your regex is matching the number at the beginning of the string. You could use `^$` to match string length (beginning and end), truncate the string first, use strip_tags, etc.

Example:

http://www.regexr.com/3bmfm

`^\+([0-9])([ .-]*\d){7,12}$`

Remove the `^` and `$` from beginning and end of pattern to see it match the second line.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response. That resolved the issue.

Answer (score -5):

Because you specified how many times a given pattern should be repeated by `{7,12}`.

Comment: While technically accurate, this doesn't really explain what Java did wrong in any meaningful depth, nor does it offer any helpful suggestions.